# Youtubeplayer in android app stops playing after 20-25 seconds

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play youtube videos in my android app using Youtube API and following is the code which i have written

activity_fetch_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    ></FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

and in java this is how initialize YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and add a video ID.
FetchVideoActivity.java

```
  private void initUI(){
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment =new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtubeFragment, youTubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeConstants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(sVideoId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationFailure: ************************"+youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

I am able to initialize the fragment with my API_KEY and it starts playing video. But after 25 second this activity crashes. Please refer below for the log:

```
2019-02-25 07:50:10.440 1281-1868/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.google.android.youtube appid=10081 user=0: from pid 1281
2019-02-25 07:50:10.441 1281-1868/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3189:com.google.android.youtube/u0a81 (adj 900): stop com.google.android.youtube
2019-02-25 07:50:10.446 1281-1868/? D/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.youtube has 0 services
2019-02-25 07:50:10.455 1281-1868/? D/EmbryoManager: prepare com.google.android.youtube user 0
2019-02-25 07:50:10.456 1281-1868/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3165:com.google.android.youtube.player/u0a81 (adj 0): stop com.google.android.youtube
2019-02-25 07:50:10.462 1281-1868/? D/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.youtube.player has 1 services
2019-02-25 07:50:10.463 1281-1868/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.youtube/.api.service.YouTubeService in 1000ms
2019-02-25 07:50:10.468 1281-1868/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3055:my.app.package/u0a1047 (adj 0): stop com.google.android.youtube
2019-02-25 07:50:10.470 1281-1868/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{71579f2 u0 my.app.package/.FetchVideoActivity t159}: app died, no saved state
2019-02-25 07:50:10.477 1281-1868/? I/WindowManager: Failed to capture screenshot of Token{278d843 ActivityRecord{71579f2 u0 cmy.app.package/.FetchVideoActivity t159 f}} appWin=Window{6dc7c16 u0 my.app.package/.FetchVideoActivity} drawState=4
2019-02-25 07:50:10.485 577-868/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer (my.app.package/my.app.package.FetchVideoActivity#0) in layer parent (no-parent).
2019-02-25 07:50:10.524 1281-2919/? D/MediaSessionService: Destroying com.google.android.youtube/YouTube playerlib (userId=0)
```

Is there anything I am missing? I already wasted a lot of time fixing this issue.

Comment: How are you testing, on what device (make/model/OS version/Play Services/rooted/stock)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang i am testing this on One Plus 3. Android Version 8.0.0. Its not rooted.

Comment: I suggest to attach   `youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener` and see what goes wrong . you might get any log related to scenario

Comment: @TejasPandya Sure. I shall check that once i go home.  I will get back to you once tested. Thanks mate :)